# PowerApps seemingly has me stuck in a loop

Tags: powerapps, power-platform

I work for various clients and am required to log in using different accounts to various parts of Azure and Power Platform. Recently, I switched account to access another client's Power App while in Power Apps already. It took me back to the main Power Apps page and I clicked 'sign in'. Note that I had finished with the prior client's app and no longer have access to the login that was being used there. For some reason, when I clicked 'sign in', it automatically tried to take me to the previous client's power app and I got the "You don't have access to this" error, as expected. However, when I try to sign out and change what I'm accessing, I only get the option to change my user login, not the power app I'm accessing, so I'm stuck in a type of 'loop' of Power Apps trying to log me into another client's App, getting denied and logged out, then trying to log me back in again to the same app. Is there a way to change what environment I am trying to access without actually having access to PowerApps?

[image: I try to log in here]

[image: I get this error and then click 'sign in']

[image: I get this and click "sign out and sign in with a different account"]

At this point I can't do anything because the only account I can use is tied to a different client's environment. I need to be able to switch environments without access to essentially any environment because I can't get past the login.

I've tried clearing the browser history and cache to no avail. I'm able to access it using a private window, but I shouldn't have to do that just to get access.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to connect to :

- https://login.microsoftonline.com/
- https://portal.office.com/

You can also start a new browser in `private mode` to test if your account is working! With the new Edge (or Chrome with a plugin), you can have profiles, so you can switch between Microsoft 365 accounts.

Comment: Same. I have a different profile per client and it works well!